# Use bash wait in for-loop

Tags: bash, shell

(I have searched and expected this question to have been asked before but couldn't find anything like this although there are plenty of similar questions)

I want this for-loop to run in 3 different threads/processes and `wait` seem to be the right command

```
for file in 1.txt 2.txt 3.text 4.txt 5.txt
        do something lengthy &
        i=$((i + 1))
        wait $!
done
```

But this construct, I guess, just starts one thread and then wait until it is done before it starts the next thread. I could place `wait` outside the loop but how do I then

1. Access the pids?
2. Limit it to 3 threads?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want five mutually independent tasks to be processed in three threads (with queuing as-it-happens) and the sole purpose of `wait` is to make sure that nothing else happens before all five have exited?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to give `wait` a PID.  If you call `wait` with no arguments it will wait on all background processes, so putting the `wait` after `done` will wait for all threads to complete.  Not sure how to limit to 3 threads though...

Comment: @Dario I have two functions, 1 and 2. 1 (the one above) can be paralleliliced but 2 can't be run until all 5 files are processed. I have 4 cores and I need to leave one alone so everything else can run uninterrupted. If I understand your question correctly the anser is "yes",

Comment: These are *processes,* not *threads.*

Comment: `bash` by itself isn't really suitable for maintaining a process pool like this.

Comment: Could you describe how the similar questions you found *weren't* suited? ("I considered specific-other-question X, but it was suitable only for Y and my situation is Z"). Otherwise, it's hard to know *why* this shouldn't be closed as duplicative, since this is a general request we get a lot, and have answered and re-answered numerous times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jobs` builtin can list the currently running background jobs, so you can use that to limit how many you create. To limit your jobs to three, try something like this:

```
for file in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt; do
  if [ $(jobs -r | wc -l) -ge 3 ]; then
    wait $(jobs -r -p | head -1)
  fi

  # Start a slow background job here:
  (echo Begin processing $file; sleep 10; echo Done with $file)&
done
wait # wait for the last jobs to finish
```

Comment: More than one job could complete by the time the job you choose to wait on completes. This isn't a good way to keep your process pool busy.

Comment: (`wait -n`, introduced in `bash` 4.3, is an improvement, in that you only have to block until an arbitrary process completes, but that doesn't mean that *only* one process has completed, and jobs can continue to complete while you are deciding how many new processes you can start.)

Comment: True, although more importantly the job that we're waiting on may actually be the last of the three to finish -- who knows -- so it's not optimal. As you say in the question comments, bash on its own isn't really suitable for managing concurrency. However, given the bash primitives, this is a relatively simple way to avoid going over the process limit, even though it may underutilize the pool.

Answer (score 3):

The GNU Parallel might be worth a look.

My first attempt,

```
parallel -j 3 'bash -c "sleep {};   echo {};"' ::: 4 1 2 5 3
```

can be, according to the inventor of parallel, be shortened to

```
parallel -j3 sleep {}\; echo {} ::: 4 1 2 5 3
1
2
4
3
5
```

and masking the semicolon, more friendly to type, like this:

```
parallel -j3 sleep {}";" echo {} ::: 4 1 2 5 3
```

works too.

It doesn't look trivial and I only tested it 2 times so far, once to answer this question. parallel --help shows a source where there is more info, the man page is a little bit shocking. :)

```
parallel -j 3 "something lengthy {}" ::: {1..5}.txt
```

might work, depending on `something lengthy` being a program (fine) or just bashcode (afaik, you can't just call a bash function in parallel with parallel).

On xUbuntu-Linux 16.04, parallel wasn't installed but in the repo.

Comment: First example shorter: `parallel -j3 sleep {}\; echo {} ::: 4 1 2 5 2`

Comment: @OleTange: Hi Ole, and thanks for parallel. Seen 3 or 4 of your videos so far, and tutorial is open in one of the 40 tabs, waiting for me to have some more time.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Rob Davis' answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
qty=3

for file in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt; do
    while [ `jobs -r | wc -l` -ge $qty ]; do
        sleep 1
        # jobs #(if you want an update every second on what is running)
    done
    echo -n "Begin processing $file"
    something_lengthy  $file &
    echo $!
done
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subshell approach example

```
 ( (sleep 10) &
    p1=$!
    (sleep 20) &
    p2=$!
    (sleep 15) &
    p3=$!
    wait
    echo "all finished ..." )
```

Note wait call wait for all child inside a subshell, you can use modulo operator (%) with 3 and use the reminder to check for 1st 2nd and 3rd process id (if needed) or can use it to run 3 parallel thread.
Hope this helps.